# Stop process output from being displayed in project command window

Tags: c#, shell, command-line, process

I'm starting an exe via the Process class and I've noticed that the exe's output is being displayed inside my application's command window. *Note - when I start up the exe, I make sure a window is not opened - so, the only window that displays when my application is running is my main application, project.exe.

Is there a way to stop the exe's output from being displayed inside my project.exe command window? Here is my code:

```
Process process = new Process();
string exePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingDir, exeString);
process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Logger.LogInfo(e.Data);

process.Start();

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I've even tried setting RedirectStandardOutput to false with:

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

and the output is still placed in the command window.

Comment: process.BeginOutputReadLine();
 process.WaitForExit();   should be after the process has started. i.e after the process.Start()

Comment: My fault - that's a typo - thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @loneshark99 Testing it now - but where did you get Dump() from? That isn't a string class method.

Comment: I tried in Linqpad for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works when I tried locally on my box. Can you give it a try by replacing the exe path/name.

From MSDN doc's.

"When a Process writes text to its standard stream, that text is typically displayed on the console. By setting RedirectStandardOutput to true to redirect the StandardOutput stream, you can manipulate or suppress the output of a process. For example, you can filter the text, format it differently, or write the output to both the console and a designated log file"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

```
void Main()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    string exePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\SourceCode\CS\DsSmokeTest\bin\Debug", "DsSmokeTest.exe");
    process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\SourceCode\CS\DsSmokeTest\bin\Debug";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Empty;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Test(e.Data);
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void Test(string input)
{
    input.Dump();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On .Net 8 all i had to do was add `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;` and the output was not shown on my app's console

full code:

```cs
Process process = new()
process.StartInfo.FileName = appPath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score -1):

just add the following line

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```